# How i mock grails domain.refresh()

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I running a unit test in grails service, but in the code i have a refresh gorm call, broke unit test.

Unit test

```
def unitMeasureMock = mockFor(UnitMeasure)
unitMeasureMock.demand.static.get() { Long id -> unit }
unitMeasureMock.demand.static.refresh(){unit}
```

In service code

```
UnitMeasure netWeightPalletUnitMeasure = UnitMeasure.get(pallet.netWeightPalletUnitMeasure.id)
        netWeightPalletUnitMeasure.refresh()
```

The mock for refresh method doesn´t work.

How i mock gorm refresh method correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking `refresh()` as a static method on `UnitMeasure` but in your service you are calling `refresh()` on an instance of `UnitMeasure`. In order to intercept this with your mock you need to mock the instance method:

```
unitMeasureMock.demand.refresh() { unit }
```